# How exactly is used the layer concept in OpenLayer 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I am evaluating to use **OpenLayer 3** into a project.

I am studying some tutorial about this library and I have the following doubt about the layer concept.

So, from what I have understand (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion) to render a simple "Hello World" map example I can have something like this:

```
var view = new ol.View2d({
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 0
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: map,        // map is the id of the element in the DOM where the map will be putted
    layers: [layer],
    view: view          // Use the previous defined view object for the settings of this map
});
```

I have not yet test this example on my PC, I have take it from this videotutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPPhpLTkWX8

So it seems that there is a separation of the **map** and the **view* where

- **Map:** is the primary object with which the user interacts (click on, drag and drop, draw, do operations).
- **View:** contains the settings related to how the **Map** is rendered (in this case it is a bidimensional map where it is specified where the map is centered when it is displayed and the zoom).

So from what I have understand there is this separation of concern because I can have a single **Map** that can be displayed in different way using differents **View** objects.

Is it this reasoning correct or am I missing something?

And not the first big doubt: in the tutorial show that the previous code display a map into the browser. Ok, but from where is take this map? Is it a GoogleMap map or what? This is pretty obscure for me...

Then the tutorial go on and show the **layer concept**.

So it show this code that create an **Open Street Map** layer (https://www.openstreetmap.org):

```
var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM();
});
```

and then I think that to use this layer I have to add it as element to the previous **layers: [layer]** array defined into the **map** object. Is it correct?

Now the thing that I have not so clear in my mind is.

What is a layer? Is it something like additional information added on a specific map or is it a special kind of Map (for example Google Maps or some other kind of map obtained from some other map provider).

I think that it is the first one (some data showed as a layer on the map, infact on the **map** object I have a **layers** array as field in which I think I cann add more then one layer to show differents information on this map).

But I have this doubt because I can't understand who is the map provider in OpenLayer (Google Maps or what?) and if I can also speciy a specific Map Provider.

This doubt is also generated because I have see that using OpenLayer I can use **Bing Map** as layer but from what I know **Bing Map** is a map provider alternative to **Google Maps**.

```
var bing= new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
        key: API KEY,
        style: setted style
    })
});
```

So how exactly works?

Comment: No feedback? You got a great answer!

Comment: @JonatasWalker I have read it only now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That are a lot of questions at once, let me try to answer some:

> So from what I have understand there is this separation of concern because I can have a single Map that can be displayed in different way using differents View objects.
>
> Is it this reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Actually it is the other way round. Different maps can share the same [view](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html). Here is an example:
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/side-by-side.html

> Ok, but from where is take this map? Is it a GoogleMap map or what? This is pretty obscure for me...
>   ...
>   What is a layer?

A map is a collection of layers. And a layer is a visual representation of a geographical dataset/datasource (e.g. vector features, raster tiles and images). For example:

```
var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM();
});
```

This defines a tile layer which use OpenStreetMap tile images as the source. If you replace the source with `ol.source.BingMaps`, your layer will use tile images from Bing.

> But I have this doubt because I can't understand who is the map provider in OpenLayer (Google Maps or what?) and if I can also speciy a specific Map Provider.
>
> This doubt is also generated because I have see that using OpenLayer I can use Bing Map as layer but from what I know Bing Map is a map provider alternative to Google Maps.

OpenLayers is a library to create interactive maps. OpenLayers is not a data provider, but it allows to use data from different providers, e.g. the tiles from OpenStreetMap or Bing.

Google has a JavaScript library, the Google Maps JavaScript API, but Google is also a data provider of their street map and satellite imagery tiles.

I hope this makes it a bit clearer. I recommend you to take a look at the [OpenLayers 3 Workshop](http://openlayers.org/workshop/) and at [mapschool.io](http://mapschool.io/) and/or [Learning Lunches: How to Make a Map](https://github.com/veltman/learninglunches/tree/master/maps)  to better understand the basics.